# Kaa - Avro logicalType

Tags: kaa

I tried to upload an Avro schema file into Kaa. I had a field of type logicalType introduced in the log schema. But after I uploaded and created the log schema, I downloaded and checked the schema. The field logicalType was removed.

Does Kaa support logicalType as supported by Avro? If not, is there any future plans to support it?

Answer (score 0):

Kaa doesn't support logicalType. There are no plans to implement one but you can create a feature request on [Kaa JIRA](http://jira.kaaproject.org/projects/KAA/summary/).